# How to close devexpress popup from controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress-mvc

I have created popup which contain a strongly typed view with submit button. When user click on submit button I am going to save data into database in post action method. Now I want to close that popup when data get saved & display parent page from which that popup was opened.

Following is the code
HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult SendProduct(string rowId)
    {
        Product objProduct = new Product();
        return View(objProduct);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendProduct(Product objProduct)
    {
        return View(objProduct);
    }
}
```

Product model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Index.chtm

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView
@using UI.Infrastructure.Resources;
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnBeginCallback(s, e) {
        e.customArgs["rowId"] = 123;
    }
    function Click() {
        pcSendProduct.PerformCallback();
        if (!pcSendProduct.IsVisible())
            pcSendProduct.Show();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:Click()">Enumalate menu click</a>
<div>
   @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                                   {
                                       settings.Name = "btnSend";
                                       settings.Width = 80;
                                       settings.Text = "Find";
                                       settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                                       settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ Click(); }}");
                                   }).GetHtml()
</div>
  @Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "pcSendProduct";
        settings.Width = 1050;
        settings.Height = 550;
        settings.HeaderText = "Plan Customer Interaction";
        settings.CloseAction = DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CloseAction.CloseButton;
        settings.Styles.Header.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        settings.Styles.Header.VerticalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.VerticalAlign.Middle;
        settings.Styles.Header.Font.Size = 10;
        settings.Modal = true;
        settings.ShowHeader = true;
        settings.ShowCloseButton = true;
        settings.CloseAction = DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CloseAction.CloseButton;
        settings.Left = 1245;
        settings.Top = 300;
        settings.Styles.ModalBackground.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        settings.ContentUrl = Url.Action("PlanCustomerInteraction", "PlanCustomerInteraction");
        settings.ShowLoadingPanel = true;
        settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "OnBeginCallback";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "OnPopupEndCallback"; 
    }).GetHtml()
```

SendProduct.cshtml

```
    @model Demo.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendProduct";
}

<h2>SendProduct</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So after saving data in SendProduct POST action method I want to close Send product popup.

Please give me solution to close popup controll from controller action method.​

Comment: From parent page button click I am calling javascript function & in that function I have written popup.Show() method to open that popup.

Comment: Can you post your javascript code? What plugin do you use?

Comment: I have modify my post which contain sample code.

Comment: Please actually post the javascript file related to the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller runs on the server, while your popup is on the client, so you need to add the logic to close the popup at the right time in the client/javascript code.